# Saving image in plot window after placing points in plot

Tags: image-processing, octave

Using Octave, I am able to show a image and then plot some red circles over it, as follow:

```
tux = imread('tux.png');
imshow(tux);
hold on;
plot(100,100,'r','markersize', 10);
plot(150,200,'r','markersize', 10);
```

The above code display this window:

[image: Image with red circles plotted over]

My question is: *How can I save this image as it is being showed inside the window?*

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple.  Use:

```
print -djpg image.jpg
```

[`print`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html) is a command in Octave that allows you to capture what's currently seen in the current figure window.  `-d` specifies what output device you want to write to.  There are multiple "devices" you can use to save to file... EPS, PS, TEX, etc.  A device can also be an image writer, and so here I chose JPEG.  You can choose other valid image formats that are supported by Octave.  Take a look at the link I provided above for more details.

After, you just specify what file name you want to save the plot to.  In this case, I chose `image.jpg`.

You can also take a look at `saveas`.  Make sure you get a handle to the current figure first before doing so:

```
h = gcf;
saveas(h, "image.jpg");
```

Also... a more point-and-click approach would be to Go to `File -> Save As` in the figure that your image is displayed in :)

Comment: Hahah that third one is the most used, actually :D

Comment: btw, do you know what is the difference between `print` and `saveas`? because I couldn't tell ... output formats maybe?

Comment: @KeillRandor - lol. As for your second question, it looks like `saveas` is a more simplified version of `print`: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html .  `saveas` allows you to save in image formats as well as PDF.  `print` seems to be more general and it also provides a lot more options with respect to what is done to the output file when saving.  If I had to make an educated guess, `saveas` is for n00bs, while `print` is for those who know what they're doing. lol.

Comment: @rayryeng  thank you for your answer. It is very close to the KeillRandor's one. I don't know which should be marked as the right answer.  PS: I upvoted both.

Comment: @VitorLima, mark this one, he also answered mine ;D

Comment: @KeillRandor - lol. That's very diplomatic of you.  Thanks :)  I've upvoted your answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `print` to save your plot to a file:

```
print (FILENAME, OPTIONS)    // for the current figure
print (H, FILENAME, OPTIONS) // for the figure handle H
```

and also take a look to `saveas`

```
saveas (H, FILENAME)
```